# Error while upgrading WordPress - Fatal error: Out of memory

Tags: php, wordpress, fatal-error

When I am trying to upgrade WordPress (current version 3.1) to WordPress 3.2.2, I am getting this stage error:

> Fatal error: Out of memory (allocated 29360128) (tried to allocate 3155893 bytes) in /homepages/32/d108770064/htdocs/Wordpress/wp-includes/class-http.php on line 1420

How to fix this and update WordPress?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only thing you could do is try and uninstall the old WordPress 3.1. 
Then, download WordPress 3.2.2 from the website and install the new version.

Comment: Why anyone will uninstall the WordPress 3.1? Anyways, I tried to [upgrade WordPress manually](http://codex.wordpress.org/Updating_WordPress#Manual_Update). And it worked. Now no errors.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to post more information if you want us to help, such as server load, server specs, etc. But what @Giggsey said is mostly right; you'll want to download a fresh copy of Wordpress and see if that works. However, make sure you back up your files.

Answer (score 0):

If you can access your PHP configuration, try increasing `memory_limit` to `32M` or `64M` and restart the web server.